# Unable to run a fetch operation in backboneJS

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

Here's a fetch operation I've written in a view:

```
this.collection.fetch ({
            data:{
                values: 100,
                type: "normal"
            },
            success:(collection, response) => {
                _.each(collection.models, (model) => {
                    Log.show(model.get("question"));
                })
            },
            error: (err) => {
                Log.error("couldn't receive data");
            }
        });
```

My Webstorm throws an error on `fetch({})` that says `Supplied Parameters are incorrect`

I'm not able to find any other api specification for the fetch call. The code is in and the typescript definition for backbone I'm using is here:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/backbone/backbone.d.ts

UPDATE==

The result I see in the log is this:

```
Triple
Triple
Triple
Triple
Triple
```

Here "triple" is the value of the "question" attribute in the last model added to the collection. There are 5 models in the collection (in the persistent) database and if there were 6 it would display "Triple" 6 times. There is some problem in the API call I made to get the value of the question object

I'm probably not calling the function right. I need to know whats the appropriate call for getting the value of an attribute from the model. Or this could be a problem actually retrieving the values from the server.

I've tried the following to actually get the right value in the log:

```
Log.show(model.toJSON().question);
Log.show(model.toString());
Log.show(model.question);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success callback should look like this:

```
success:function(collection, response){}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'd done earlier, but that didn't work, so I changed to this.

Comment: Did you add a console.log in the success/error callback as proposed? Either way, you should receive a message. If not, also check the scope of this, and `console.log(this.collection instanceof Backbone.Collection);`

Comment: Sorry, apparently you're using typescript, which I wasn't aware of, and which I don't have experience with. Still, either syntax you use, the proposed solution should work as well. If not, debug it as proposed in my previous comment. If you're using Chrome, also check the network tab to check if a request is actually made to the server.

Comment: Gyson Hi. I've updated the question to show the logs which has a problem too. I appreciate your help.